# Read information from SQL Azure procedure and pass to JS variable

Tags: javascript, sql, azure

I am working on Azure / Windows Phone 8 project.

I have procedure called 'RegisterUser', and API called 'registeruser'. I want to send information from procedure to my application with sasUrl variable. How can I read anything what returns procedure, for example if it raiseerror or just send Users.ID and pass that information to my variable sasUrl?

## JavaScript in Azure API

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
var login = request.body.login;
var sasUrl = 'Message';
//var key = request.query.key;

request.service.mssql.query(
'exec RegisterUser ' + login + ';', {
    success: function(results) {
        sasUrl = 'Executed';
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, { SASUrl : sasUrl });
        },
     error: function(results) {
        sasUrl = 'Error';
        response.send(statusCodes.Error, { SASUrl : sasUrl });
     }
        
        });
}
```

## Procedure

```
DECLARE @newid int;
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from Users Where Users.Login like @Login)
 BEGIN
  set @newid = (SELECT MAX(Users.ID) from Users);
  set @newid = @newid + 1;
  INSERT INTO Users (ID, Login, KeyID, RightID) VALUES (@newid, @Login, 100, 100);
  Select Users.ID from Users where Users.Login like @Login;
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
 RAISERROR ('Użytkownik już istnieje, rejestracja się nie powiodła',10, 1) 
 END
END
;
```

Comment: Are you able to debug js code? Can you share what you get in result in success method?

Comment: No because it's for custom Api's for Azure Mobile Service. There is just syntax check nothing more. I can evaluate code after save with my browser, but still it's connected with Windows Phone 8 project, where request looks like 'var sas = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<RegisterUser, SASResponse>("registeruser", user);'